# How to trigger ajax requests in loop based on previous ajax response

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have list of selected shipping address for each address need updating quantity attribute, based on previous update response if previous update is failed need abort the loop.

Here is my current code snippet.

```
    $scope.applyQty = (qty) ->
      collections = $filter('filter')($scope.address, {checked: true}, true) #return array of objects
      x = true
      angular.forEach(collections, (address) ->    
        if x
          address.quantity = qty    
          promise = $scope.saveMethod(address)
          promise.then ( (respone) ->
            #dosomething     
          ), (error) ->
            x = false #stop next address
          )
...
$scope.saveMethod = (address) ->
  deferred = $q.defer()
  #some logic
  ..
  #ajax call to update quantity
  address.save().then ((response) ->
    deferred.resolve(response)
  ), (error) ->
    deferred.reject(error)
    address.quantity = 0

  return deferred.promise;
```

In applyQty method looping selected shipping address calling the saveMethod. If one address is failed to update in server side stop the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use $q service in appropriate way as us return promise to the next execution, I simulate this code with

```
var chaingAjax = function(item) {
  // smiulte ajax request
  var defer = $q.defer();

  $timeout(function() {
    // assume error happen at item 4 execution will end and return error message
    if (item != 4) {
      defer.resolve(item);
      console.log('posted ' + item)
    } else {
      console.log('error 4')
      return defer.reject({
        error: 'bad call ajax stoped at ' + item
      });
    }
  }, 500);

  return defer.promise;
}

var executeList = function(list) {
  console.log(list)
  var item = list.pop()
  var promise = chaingAjax(item).then(function(saved) {
    console.log(saved)
    executeList(list)
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  });
  return promise
}


executeList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
  .then(function() {
    $scope.value = "all done";
  }, function(e) {
    $scope.value = e.error;
  });
```

And you can use $http.post() or any function returning promise

```
var exeuteMyAjaxCall =  function (list){
    var item = list.pop();
    var promise = $http.post('url', {data:item})
                  .then(function(success){
                       exeuteMyAjaxCall(list);
                   },function(error){ 
                   })

    return promise;
}


exeuteMyAjaxCall (arrayOfData)
  .then(function() {
    $scope.value = "all done";
  }, function(e) {
    $scope.value = e.error;
  });
```